# MantineReactTable data does not display

Tags: reactjs, mantine

I try to display the result of a query with MantineReactTable.
The data is available as I can download it well, but is is not dislaying in my table (all rows are blank):

The getDataFromFastmagSql is an async function than get data from an ERP system using EDI. It get a Text response from it and parse it to have a proper Object.

[image]

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import getDataFromFastmagSql from "../Services/getDataFromFastmagSql";
import { Box, Button, Container, Grid } from "@mantine/core";
import { MRT_ColumnDef, MRT_Row, MantineReactTable } from "mantine-react-table";
import { IconDownload } from "@tabler/icons-react";
import { ExportToCsv } from "export-to-csv";

function TableResult() {
  
  const [dataSet, setData] = useState([]);
  const [columnSet, setColumns] = useState<MRT_ColumnDef[]>([]);
  const columns = useMemo<MRT_ColumnDef[]>(() => columnSet, [columnSet]);

  function prepareColumns() {
    getDataFromFastmagSql("SELECT * FROM produits LIMIT 15")
      .then((fetchedData) => {
        const fetchedColumns = Object.keys(fetchedData[0]).map((key) => ({
          header: key,
          accessor: key,
          id: key,
        }));
        setColumns(fetchedColumns);
        setData(fetchedData);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Col span={12}>
          <Button variant="light" onClick={async () => {prepareColumns()} }>Run this ma caille</Button>
          <MantineReactTable
            columns={columns}
            data={dataSet}
            enableRowSelection
            enableColumnOrdering
            enableGlobalFilter={false} //turn off a feature
          />
        </Grid.Col>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
}
export default TableResult;
```